# Remove words with specific ending from variable in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

currently I have this code:

```
// main title of product
$maintitle = 'CHICKENBUFFET HOT WINGS';

// take first word from $maintitle and put in new variable
list($title1) = explode(' ', $maintitle);

// words that start with CHICKEN are removed and put in new variable
$title2 = preg_replace('/(CHICKEN)\w+/', '', $maintitle);

// echo titles
echo $title1;
echo $title2;
```

This works fine, however I don't want to remove words that start with CHICKEN, but words that ending with BUFFET. I think it has something to with my REGEX in the preg_replace line, but I can't seem to find the correct expression.

Thanks advance!

Comment: It is not quite clear. [`preg_replace('/\b\w*BUFFET\b/', '', $maintitle)`](https://ideone.com/3peOX4)?

Comment: There is no need to put `CHICKEN` in parentheses and a `regex` that matches a "word that **start** with `CHICKEN`" is `/^CHICKEN/`. Without `^` it matches `CHICKEN` in the middle of the string too.

Comment: ... or maybe i misread, you want `buffet` kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

`#\w+BUFFET#`

Any word ending in BUFFET will match.

```
<?php

// main title of product
$maintitle = 'CHICKENBUFFET HOT WINGS';

// take first word from $maintitle and put in new variable
list($title1) = explode(' ', $maintitle);

// words that start with CHICKEN are removed and put in new variable
$title2 = preg_replace('/\w+BUFFET/', '', $maintitle);

// echo titles
echo $title1."\n";
echo trim($title2);
```

Which will output :

```
CHICKENBUFFET 
HOT WINGS
```

Try it here: https://3v4l.org/FbMjk

Comment: I added another BUFFET to the string. It remains. https://3v4l.org/CApMM

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was trying to make :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey, one last question, how do I make the last 4 lines also included till BUFFET? [link](https://regex101.com/r/iAtEVs/1/)

Answer (score 2):

As you need string end with BUFFET make changes as below

```
$title2 = preg_replace('/\w+(BUFFET)/', '', $maintitle);
```

Full code

```
$maintitle = 'CHICKENBUFFET HOT WINGS';

// take first word from $maintitle and put in new variable
list($title1) = explode(' ', $maintitle);

// words that start with CHICKEN are removed and put in new variable
$title2 = preg_replace('/\w+(BUFFET)/', '', $maintitle); // changed this line

// echo titles
echo $title1;
echo "<br/>";
echo $title2;
```